# Constructing a search phrase that orders output according to match closeness

Tags: ms-access

I've gained invaluable help from this forum in the past - many thanks! I'd be grateful for a little more help with a new problem.

Below is part of a table comprising  5 fields (ID, F1-F4). The table extends downwards several thousand records.

```
Table1 
ID   F1  F2   F3    F4

1    A    B    1    2
2    A         2    4
3    D    C    8    
4    F    E    4    6
5         B         2
6    D    F    3    
7    B    B         3
8    N    L    1    9
9    A    A    0    7
```

A few rules: 
Note that the entries in columns F1 and F2 can be present in either field. Similarly for F3 and F4. Entries in F1 and F2 are never present in F3 and F4, and vice versa.
Single Null entries can be present in F1 or F2.
Single Null entries can also be present in F3 or F4.
However, Nulls in both F1 AND F2 (and/or) F3 AND F4 will never be present.

**Initial problem (solved):**

I would like to search this table for matches involving permutations of a user-entered search phrase, such as:

```
F1    F2    F3    F4 
A     B     1     2
```

A conditional construct like the following will achieve this by allowing for permutations between F1/F2 and F3/F4 Nulls.

"WHERE (F1 In (‘A’,’B’) OR F1 Is Null) AND (F2 In (‘A’,’B’) OR F2 Is Null)

AND (F3 In (1,2) OR F3 Is Null) AND (F4 In (1,2) OR F4 Is Null)"

VBA is used to construct the “In (..)” statements based on the user’s search phrase. For the above, the record set will contain records 1 and 5 (record 5 is allowed since it does not contain entries out with the search phrase, but may include Nulls).

**New problem (unsolved – I’m struggling a bit on this):**

As an added feature, and to greatly benefit the end user, I would now like to display records closest to the search phrase (4/4 Match) ordered to those furthest away (0/4 Match)  i.e.:

```
ID    F1    F2    F3    F4    Matches

1     A     B     1     2      4
5           B           2      4
2     A           2     4      2
7     B     B           3      2
9     A     A     0     7      2
5           B           7      1
8     N     L     1     9      1
3     D     C     8            0
4     F     E     4     6      0
6     D     F     3            0
```

Note the new field, Matches, that displays the number of acceptable matches between search phrase and search table.
Note that Nulls count towards a match. Note also that entries in the search phrase can be duplicated and count towards an acceptable match (F1 and F2 fields in records 7 and 9), again, hence the sql construct above.

Is it possible to do this relatively painlessly in sql?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calculate a sum for each row and order on the result (descending): `case when F1 in ('A','B') or F1 is NULL then 1 else 0 end + case when F2 in ('A','B') or F2 is NULL then 1 else 0 end + ... as Matches`

Comment: CASE is not valid in Access, use IIF to replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic outline is:

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, (IIF function statements here) AS Matches 
FROM Table1 ORDER BY (repeat the IIF statements here) DESC;
```

Unfortunately, we cannot use a field-alias in the ORDER BY clause with Access, which is why the IIF statements need to be repeated.

The IIFs would be like:

```
IIF(F1='A',1,0) + IIF(..)
```

but you'll need to nest a few IIFs.

Comment: Fantastic! I've just tested this out and it works like a charm. (IIF (F1='A',1,IIF (F1='B',1,IIF (F1 Is Null,1,0))) + IIF(…etc...)).  
I've also tested out using a field number in place of repeating the IIF's to order the output, i.e.  ORDER BY 5 DESC;      
Thank you so much :)